# How to reduce duplicate code in C# for similar functions on different types

Tags: c#

I have these two functions that do essentially the same thing but one is a float based version, the other an int based version. It drives me crazy that i have to write it twice, is there a smart way to design my code to avoid this kinda thing in C#, the more funcitons i add to these two types that essentially have the same behaviour, the more tedious this is becoming....

```
    public static Span2D operator +(Span2D A, Span2D B)
    {
        float minX = A.MinX < B.MinX ? A.MinX : B.MinX;
        float minY = A.MinY < B.MinY ? A.MinY : B.MinY;
        float maxX = A.MaxX > B.MaxX ? A.MaxX : B.MaxX;
        float maxY = A.MaxY > B.MaxY ? A.MaxY : B.MaxY;
        return new Span2D(minX,minY,maxX,maxY);
    }

    public static Span2DInt operator +(Span2DInt A, Span2DInt B)
    {
        int minX = A.MinX < B.MinX ? A.MinX : B.MinX;
        int minY = A.MinY < B.MinY ? A.MinY : B.MinY;
        int maxX = A.MaxX > B.MaxX ? A.MaxX : B.MaxX;
        int maxY = A.MaxY > B.MaxY ? A.MaxY : B.MaxY;
        return new Span2DInt(minX, minY, maxX, maxY);
    }
```

Span2D and Span2DInt are structs by the way if that matters.

Comment: Why did you delete your question on the rounding of `float`s?

Comment: @Enigmativity more info on it is now here: 
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/402381/how-to-do-grid-systems-with-floats-given-precision-causes-problems

Comment: You can edit your question and get it re-opened if you can make it an original question rather than a duplicate.

Comment: But you didn't have enough information to identify what the actual issue was - so hence it was a duplicate. You needed to flesh out your problem more fully so that we could give you a practical answer.

Comment: The added issue was the code wasn't wrong, so it didn't belong on SO anyway, it was an engineering problem you're welcome to give your insights to the question i linked anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Generic for this:

```
struct Span2D<Type: IComparable> {
    Type MinX { get; };
    Type MaxX { get; };
    ...
}

public Span2D<Type> operator+(Span2D<Type> A, Span2D<Type> B) {

    Type minX = A.MinX < B.MinX ? A.MinX : B.MinX; // as normal...

}
```

Comment: Is IComparable needed for generics ?

Comment: Yes, so that you can compare > / <

Comment: But you're not trying to use `IComparable`, you're trying to use `<`, which won't work. I'd also *strongly* advise against using the name `Type` as a type parameter, and I suspect you want to constrain the type parameter to implement the *generic* `IComparable<T>` interface instead of the non-generic one.

Comment: What would happen if some one used a string type - won't this just break the + operator since it makes no sense to return a string?